# Export a SQL query to XML file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to export a SQL query in SQL Server to an XML file.
So far, I have made ​​a query that is:

```
select * 
from 
products 
for xml path ('product'), root ('Products');
```

With this query, the result is correct, but I have not found a way to export it to a file.

My idea is to make the export from SQL Management Studio, if possible.
If this option is not possible, I would like to give me a hand to find out what other options I can use.

The other options I've seen are SQLCMD and .NET with Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

In Management Studio:

1. Run query as above.
2. Click on XML link in results - this will open the XML in a new window.
3. Navigate to new windown and File -> Save As - this should save as XML by default.

A bit of a manual process but maybe useful for an ad-hoc scenario?

Comment: Hi Ian Preston
Thank you for your prompt response. This method already mentioned that I tested and it works, I wanted to see if there is a process to automate the task, ie, in the same "select" export could do because once you have the order to do what I want to be a bat or a script to automatically export every "X" time to generate the report automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others who will be looking for this answer.

This can be achieved in two ways.
use `EXEC xp_cmdshell` and add queryout "Report.xml" in the syntax for it to save it as a xml file.

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT *FROM DataTable" queryout Report.xml -S[ServerName]
```

use `sqlcmd tool`. Like this,

just add save your query as input.sql:

```
 sqlcmd -S <your-server> -i input.sql -o Report.xml
```